# How do I select the last XHTML <span> element with a particular class in XPath?

Tags: html, xml, xhtml, xpath

My  target XHTML document (simplified) is like the following:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<span class="boris"> </span>
<span class="boris"> </span>
<span class="johnson"> </span>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to select the last  of class "boris."

The XPath expression

```
//span[@class="boris"]
```

selects all spans of class boris. How do I select the last one of these?

I've tried

```
//span[@class="boris" and last()]
```

which doesn't work because last() here refers to the last span in the WHOLE DOCUMENT.

How do I select all the spans of class boris... and then the  last one of these?

I've read 5 or 6 XPath tutorials and done a lot of Googling and I can't find a way to do this in XPath alone :(

Thanks in advance for help :)

Comment: This is FAQ:  **`position()` works against the axis direction and the default axe is `child`**

Answer (score 3):

```
(//span[@class="boris"])[last()]
```

The parens are necessary to make `last()` work the way you want. This:

```
//span[@class="boris"][last()]
```

is wrong because it would select multiple `<span class="boris">` if they were the respective last-of-their-kind within their parents:

```
<div>
  <span class="boris">#1</span><!-- this one -->
</div>
<div>
  <span class="boris">#2</span><!-- this one not -->
  <span class="boris">#3</span><!-- but this -->
</div>
<div>
  <span class="boris">#4</span><!-- and this, too -->
  <span class="other">#5</span><!-- this not -->
</div>
```

The first expression would select only one: #4. This is the one you need.

The second expression selects #1, #3 and #4, as illustrated.

---

Your try (`//span[@class="boris" and last()]`) would select *every* `<span class="boris">`, but mainly because you got it wrong: `last()` evaluates to a number. And any number other than `0` evaluates to `true` in boolean context. This means the expression can never be `false` for a `<span class="boris">`.

You must do a proper comparison for boolean: What you *meant* was

```
//span[@class="boris" and position() = last()]
```

which is still wrong, though. It selects #1 and #3, because here both `position()` and `last()` count within the parent element.

When you use `()` parens you create a new temporary node-set, and `last()` can work on that.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Tomalak. Using parentheses to create a temporary node-set is EXACTLY what I wanted to do. This is my first question on StackOverflow and I'm really impressed with the dedication of its users (you included) to answering questions. Well done :) Now I'm off to see if I can put my C++ knowledge to use and help anyone in return...

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing here, but isn't it `//span[@class="boris"][last()]`?

EDIT:

<strike>I just saw you can also nest predicates (see [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=102644&seqNum=3)), so maybe you can do: `//span[@class="boris"[last()]]`</strike>

EDIT 2:

Nope, that doesn't work. Go with the first one. By the way, I tried your `and last()` online, and it seemed to do what you wanted. Huh.